# Scroll Images Horizontally with Page Indicator

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a feature where user could able to scroll the images from left to right or from right to left. Since `Gallery` class has been deprecated, I have added a `TouchListener` on the ImageView and implemented the following method to find out touch direction as follows. I have also added radio button group to give a sense of page indicator.

It is working and functional, but I wonder is there any drawbacks of my approach? Any recommendation?

```
public class SwipeListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private int min_distance = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    View v;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        this.v = v;
        switch(event.getAction()) { // Check vertical and horizontal touches
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                upX = event.getX();
                upY = event.getY();

                float deltaX = downX - upX;
                float deltaY = downY - upY;

                //HORIZONTAL SCROLL
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > min_distance) {
                        // left or right
                        if (deltaX < 0) {
                            this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                            return true;
                        }
                        if (deltaX > 0) {
                            this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        //not long enough swipe...
                        return false;
                    }
                }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void onLeftToRightSwipe(){
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"left to right",   
                                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onRightToLeftSwipe() {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"right to left",
                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onTopToBottomSwipe() {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"top to bottom", 
                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onBottomToTopSwipe() {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"bottom to top", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here is the radio buttons at the bottom of image view.

```
         <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/radiogroup">

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton0"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton1" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />
            </RadioGroup>
```

I am getting the similar output as follows. I wonder the drawbacks of my approach?

[image]

Comment: ViewPager might be the best way to achieve this.

Comment: What is the drawback of my approach? What is advantage of using `ViewPager`? ViewPager has `touch listener` behind the scene?

Comment: [ViewpagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) would be your need.

Comment: What is the drawback of my approach? What is advantage of using ViewPager? ViewPager has touch listener behind the scene?

Comment: It is standard to use ViewPager for swipes you are trying to achieve. It creates Instances and is memory efficient.  It also has a smooth Pager Listener. I wouldn't say your approach is a drawback but the ViewPager class has been updated to be at peak performance. Then you can set pager.addOnPageChangeListener to listen to which view is currently being displayed.

Comment: @RRR, I want to be avoid of using third party libraries as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use viewpager. Add this in your xml file

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and this in your class file

```
private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
```

in onCreate method add this code

```
mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

And add this class as subclass in your main class.

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch(position){
                 case 0:
                   return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
                 case 1:
                   return new ScreenSlidePageFragment1();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am scrolling the Image actually, not a fragment. I want to know the drawback of my approach?

Comment: Viewpager helps you to maintain records. you can easily get current item on viewpager, while in your approach you have to check for current item.

Comment: I am also keeping track of page records as well. Is there any other advantages of using ViewPager?

Comment: One more thing, is your approach (view pager) shows circle like a radio button?

Comment: That's good you keep a track. I don't think any other advantages

Comment: @texas have you used a viewpager before? If not I would download a sample project and you will see how it works.

Comment: Hi Eugene, yes I have used ViewPager before, which does not have radio button, but you could scroll to other fragments. How you could put radio button in the view pager?

Comment: You can use tabLayout and set custom tab which contain radiobutton.

Comment: @jadav, yes I also tried that option but tablayout does not fit for the image scrolling very well. I want to keep radio buttons as a page indicator.

Comment: @texas I think you did not work on that properly otherwise, it is same like as your output